# i need my program to stop a user from entering an inncorrect value. java

Tags: java, input

ok im using a switch stament for a char where if a user was to type a location as 'r' a messege would come up and tell them to select the correct location. that all works fine, however i want the code not to allow the user to save an incorrect location untill the correct one is entered.

can some one just read this code and maybe tell me how its done thanks.

```
    public Property(String theAddress, int theBedrooms, char theLocation)
{
        address = theAddress;
        bedrooms = theBedrooms;
        location = theLocation;
        switch(theLocation){
            case 'n': theLocation = 'N';

            case 'N': theLocation = 'N';
                break;
            case 'e': theLocation = 'E';
            case 'E': theLocation = 'E';
                break;
            case 's': theLocation = 'S';
            case 'S': theLocation = 'S';
                break;
            case 'w': theLocation = 'W';
            case 'W': theLocation = 'W';
                break;
            default: theLocation = '0'; 
                System.out.println("###########################");
                System.out.println("# Enter Correct Location  #");
                System.out.println("#    North London = N     #");
                System.out.println("#    East London = E      #");
                System.out.println("#    South London = S     #");
                System.out.println("#    West London = W      #");
                System.out.println("###########################");
         }


}
```

Comment: Traditionally, you use a loop that does not exit until a proper input is entered.

Comment: use `while(! isCorrectOne(myString)){myString =scanner.next()}` use this for your required datatype..

Comment: Validating user input is a topic that has been covered extensively and repeatedly in a variety of places. Please perform your due diligence and make an effort to research and try this yourself first before asking.

Comment: Validating the user input in an object constructor is not a good idea, validate it BEFORE, when the user is entering the values, and throw an exception in the constructor if a bad value is still passed, just to be sure.

Comment: use SO for standard posts....first try something and if you face problem, knock doors of SO .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Think simple...
use a while loop and make the condition - falsewhen in a correct location

```
boolean isCorrect = false;
while(!isCorrect){
//your switch case here
//make isCorrect = true in cases (E,S and W)
}
```

I mean just put isCorrect = true for your cases (E,S and W)
when once the isCorrect variable gets the value true. while loop breaks and you are done :)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate  taking input until you get the correct Input :

```
takeInput:  // It is Label <---------------------
while(true){                                    |
   //Take Input Here                            |
switch(theLocation){                            |
        case 'n': theLocation = 'N';            |
                                                |
case 'N': theLocation = 'N';                    |
        break;                                  |
        case 'e': theLocation = 'E';            |
        case 'E': theLocation = 'E';            |
        break;                                  |
        case 's': theLocation = 'S';            |
        case 'S': theLocation = 'S';            |
        break;                                  |
        case 'w': theLocation = 'W';            |
        case 'W': theLocation = 'W';            |
        break;                                  |
   default: continue takeInput; //Jump to label |
    }
}
```

And break out Loop when you get the correct result

Answer (score 0):

In the method where you are taking the users input using a while loop. Something such as

```
private void takeInput(){
    boolean isValid = false;

    while(!isValid){
        //Ask for input
        if(input = 'e' || input = 's'){
            isValid = true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
        //if input isn't valid loop will be entered again
        //and user can be asked for input again
    }

    //Continue with code to save here 
}
```

The above code will work, however you will have a good few conditions in a if statement. Personally I would do something nicer like this.

```
public void takeInput(){
    boolean isValid = false;

    while(!isValid){
        //Ask for input
        if(checkIsValid(input)){
            //set isValid to true to exit loop
            isValid = true;
            //Set the location to the inputed character, make sure its upper case
            theLocation = Character.toUpperCase(input);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
        //if input isn't valid loop will be entered again
        //and user can be asked for input again
    }
    //You could then set 
    //Continue with code to save here 
}

private boolean checkIsValid(char c){
    switch(c){
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
        case 'S':
        case 's':
        case 'w':
        case 'W':
            return true;
        break;

        default:
            return false:
        break;  
    }
}
```

Which is a cleaner solution and helps your code become more readable. It will take a users input, call a helper method which checks if the input is valid. If the input is valid it will save the location to the theLocation variable (in uppercase) and exit the loop. If it's not valid it will loop again.